# Why does the first $.ajax error when passing a data object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am not sure why the first `$.ajax()` errors.  I am trying to pass the url parameters as part of the ajax data property.

Here is a fiddle to see that the first ajax call fails while the second succeeds: http://jsfiddle.net/f9e5Y/

Here is the JavaScript:

```
var urlParameters = {
  page: 1,
  api_key:'...',
  tags: 'kittens',
  method: 'flickr.photos.search',
  per_page: 3,
  format: 'json',
  jsoncallback: '?'
};

$.ajax({
  url: 'http://api.flickr.com/services/rest',
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: urlParameters,
  success: function (data) {
    console.log('ajax 1 - success');
    console.log('data');
  },
  error: function () {
    console.log('ajax 1 - error');   
  }
});

$.ajax({
  url: 'http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?page=1&api_key=...&tags=kitten&method=flickr.photos.search&per_page=3&format=json&jsoncallback=?',
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function (data) {
    console.log('ajax 2 - success');
    console.log(data);
  },
  error: function () {
    console.log('ajax 2 - error');   
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that jQuery only scans the original URL for the `callback=?` pattern, to generate and insert a random function name, not the URL it builds from `data`.

So what you are actually looking for is `data: 'jsonp'` and setting the callback parameter *name* via `jsonp: 'jsoncallback'`:

```
var urlParameters = {
  page: 1,
  api_key: '...',
  tags: 'kittens',
  method: 'flickr.photos.search',
  per_page: 3,
  format: 'json'
};

$.ajax({
  url: 'http://api.flickr.com/services/rest',
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  data: urlParameters,
  jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
  success: function (data) {
    console.log('ajax 1 - success');
    console.log('data');
  },
  error: function () {
    console.log('ajax 1 - error');   
  }
});
```

Comment: That was it!  Thank you Felix!